# Ggplot2 plotting country data results in "node stack overflow error"

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, stack-overflow

I am trying to reproduce and execute the R script resulting from this blog article (https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/09/visualization-of-covid-19-cases-in-arkansas/).

Everything run smoothly but, when reaching the last two instructions devoted to the creation of the final animation using ggplot and gganimate, I encounter a "node stack overflow error", something I have never encountered so far in my journey with R.

```
 <- ggplot(temp_sf) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = roll_capita), size = 0.25) +
  scale_fill_viridis(
    name = "7-day rolling cases: ",
    trans = "log10",
    option = "plasma",
  ) +
  ggthemes::theme_map() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.justification = "center") +
  labs(
    title = paste0("Arkansas 7-day rolling average of new COVID cases per ", scales::comma(per_capita), " residents"),
    subtitle = "Date: {frame_time}",
    caption = paste0("Image generated: ", Sys.time(), "\n", "Data source: https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19", "\n", "COVID-19 Data Repository by CSSE at Johns Hopkins University")
  ) +
  transition_time(date)

anim <- animate(
  p, 
  nframes = days + 10 + 30, 
  fps = 5, 
  start_pause = 10, 
  end_pause = 30,
  res = 96,
  width = 600,
  height = 600,
  units = "px"
)
```

The tibble involved in the ggplot call (namely temp_sf), has 17025 observation and 5 variables and is created using the following instruction:

```
temp_sf <- tigris::counties(cb = T, resolution = "500k") %>%
  mutate(GEOID = as.numeric(GEOID)) %>%
  inner_join(temp %>% select(FIPS, roll_cases, roll_capita, date), by = c("GEOID" = "FIPS")) %>%
  select(GEOID, roll_cases, roll_capita, date, geometry)
```

Do you know why such an error can occur? Is it something related to the environment on which the code is executed (an old Surface Pro 3) or it is a programming error?

Comment: Did you tried restarting R and see if the error goes away?

Comment: Yeah I tried restarting it and unfortunately it is still there

Comment: I once encountered the same "node stack overflow" error when creating and saving a plot with ggsave and ggvenndiagram. I could track it down to be related to my working environment, which was hosted in a conda environemt in which some permissions were not properly set.  I would thus focus debugging efforts on your working environment and not your particular r-code.